# zabbix How to complete installation successfully?

Tags: postgresql, centos, zabbix

CentOS 6.4
postgres 9.2
zabbix 2.0

ps

```
     1761 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: logger process                            
 1763 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                      
 1764 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process                            
 1765 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: wal writer process                        
 1766 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process               
 1767 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process 
 2257 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2259 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2260 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2261 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2262 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2263 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2264 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2265 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2266 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2280 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2282 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2283 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2284 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2285 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2286 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2287 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2288 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2289 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2290 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2291 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2292 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2293 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2294 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2295 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2296 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2298 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51084) idle       
 2299 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2300 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2301 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2302 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2303 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2304 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2305 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2306 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2307 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51085) idle       
 2308 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51086) idle       
 2309 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51087) idle       
 2310 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51088) idle       
 2311 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51089) idle       
 2312 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51090) idle       
 2313 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51091) idle       
 2315 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51093) idle       
 2316 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51094) idle       
 2317 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51095) idle       
 2318 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51096) idle       
 2319 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51097) idle       
 2320 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51098) idle       
 2321 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2322 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2323 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 2324 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51099) idle       
 2325 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51100) idle       
 2326 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51101) idle       
 2327 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51102) idle       
 2328 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51103) idle       
 2329 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51104) idle       
 2330 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51105) idle       
 2331 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51106) idle       
 2332 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix 127.0.0.1(51107) idle
```

pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local all all trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
local   zabbix      zabbix                            md5
```

postgresql.conf

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100
```

zabbix_server.conf

```
DBHost=localhost
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=zabbix
DBSocket=/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I can connect and observe zabbix database in pgAdmin wihout any problem. But during zabbix installation  in "3. Configure DB connection" I get:

> pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server:
>   Permission denied Is the server running on host
>   "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   [include/db.inc.php:99]
>       Error connecting to database

How to complete installation successfully?

Comment: More appropriate for serverfault.com; this will probably get closed shortly. Thanks for putting in a detailed question with all the error messages, versions, etc, though; +1. Weird error, "permission denied" on a TCP socket connect() call. Running some custom firewall software? SELinux?

Answer (score 2):

**Permission denied** when establishing a network connection is likely to be due to `SELinux`. Check error messages in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

Also note that `DBSocket` is for MySQL, it's ignored for PostgreSQL.
To have zabbix connect to PostgresQL through a Unix local domain socket, this would be:

```
 DBHost=/tmp     # instead of localhost
```

Comment: Problem was in SE configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Even if it is the wrong Forum, for me The answer was helpful. I always added the .s.PGSQL.5432, and this is NOT necessary. (actually it did not work :) /var/run/postgres/ is enough for debian.